# COUNT_BIG() returns as 1 even though it should be 0

Tags: sql

I have the following query:

```
SELECT     dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID, COUNT_BIG(dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID) AS AttachedLines
FROM         dbo.Enquiries INNER JOIN
                      dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID = dbo.QuoteLines.EnquiryID
GROUP BY dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID
```

Some of my enquiries have 0 `QuoteLines` attached, yet in my View, they return as 1?

Comment: It is not possible for this query (using an `INNER JOIN`) to return a count of `1` if there are no matching records in `QuoteLines`.  This must mean that there really are records in that table for the `EnquiryID` values in question.  Can you post example data (from both tables) for a particular `EnquiryID` that is showing the incorrect results?

Comment: Is this a subquery as part of a larger query? If not, you've got a serious mismatch here - `dbo.Enquiries` doesn't appear in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Pretty sure it's illustrous, with `DayBookEnquiries` synonymous to `Enquiries`. My crystal ball tells me so.

Comment: @RichardTheKiwi is correct! Yes this is a part of a larger query and in my haste I forgot to type it out correctly! Sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `COUNT_BIG(*)` to counting on a column, e.g. `COUNT_BIG(SomeColumn)` - this will skip NULLs in the column.  I assume your actual query is using a `LEFT JOIN`.

For your situation, you state

> Some of my enquiries have 0 QuoteLines attached, yet in my View, they return as 1?

Which would make the INNER JOIN fail. So you've either showed the wrong query, or the statement is incorrect. In either case, you can troubleshoot using this query:

```
SELECT dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID,
       dbo.QuoteLines.*
FROM   dbo.DayBookEnquiries INNER JOIN
       dbo.QuoteLines ON dbo.Enquiries.EnquiryID = dbo.QuoteLines.EnquiryID
```

It will show at least one record from QuoteLines.

Comment: This reads very oddly.  Do you mean...  change `COUNT_BIG(*)` to `COUNT_BIG(QuoteLines.EnquiryID)` or similar?

Comment: Ohh, I'll try dbo.QuoteLines.EnquiryID